# need to find similarities among two cells & need to extract that particular match

Tags: windows-8

I have two cells containing same name with some added texts. I want to extract the name only to another cell. and also need to check whether both the cells contain similar name or not....

please help me out......

M V RAO -ET-CD-81        ET-M V RAO
 SUKANTA SAHOO -ET-CD-82      ET-SUKANTA SAHOO
 SOUMASREE -ET-CD-83          ET-SOUMASREE
 SEBATI MAHAPATRA -ET-CD-85   ET-SEBATI MAHAPATRA
 CASH -ET-CD-86               ET-PREM PRAKASH
 PREM PRAKASH -ET-CD-87       ET-CASH
 CASH -ET-CD-88               ET-ANURADHA SINGH
 ANURADHA SINGH -ET-CD-89     ET-PREETIANJALI JAGADEV
 PREETIANJALI JAGADEV -ET-CD-90   ET-K K KAR
 K K KAR -ET-CD-91        ET-SRITAM DAS
 SRITAM DAS -ET-CD-92         ET-MRITYUNJAY KUMAR GAUTAM
 APARNA RATH -ET-CD-94        ET-TUSHAR RANJAN MOHANTY
 TUSHAR RANJAN MOHANTY -ET-CD-95  ET-ASUTOSH MOHANTY

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Excel? What version? Also, can you please give us a clearer example of the data you're working with?